# tight integration between blog and facebook page

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a self-hosted wordpress blog that I would like to get some more interaction with facebook users. Of course I can import the RSS to the page, and people will be able to post comments on fb, or click on the RSS link and post comments on the blog.

However, I would like to have all comments always be appearing on the blog – and potentially post blog entries to facebook so they get posted in full, and not just as a link to an RSS feed.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [Facebook comments for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/), I haven't used the plugin yet but I think it offers the solution you're looking for. 
To publish your full articles on Facbook, take a look at the [Facebook Static FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/). This Facebook application lets you import rss feeds wile keeping control over the layout.

Don't know if this is what your looking for but I would go with some plugins and the Facebook app.

Jonas